# Jamaa SMPP Client working example

Tags: c#, smpp

I'm using Jamaa SMPP Client

Does anyone have a working example on sending SMS?

Here is my code :

```
var textMessage = new TextMessage() { DestinationAddress = "XXXXXXXXX", SourceAddress = "XXXXXXXXX", Text = "test" };
var client = new SmppClient();
client.Properties.SystemID = "xxxx";
client.Properties.Password = "YYYY";
client.Properties.Port = ZZZZ;
client.Properties.Host = "255.255.255.255";
client.Properties.DefaultEncoding = DataCoding.SMSCDefault;
client.Properties.AddressNpi = NumberingPlanIndicator.Unknown;
client.Properties.AddressTon = TypeOfNumber.Unknown;

client.ForceConnect();
client.Start();
client.SendMessage(textMessage);
client.Shutdown();
```

But my provider is saying that I'm lacking the bind info (`Bind_transceiver`, `Bind_transmitter`, `Bind_receiver`)

Comment: did you every resolve your issue?

Comment: yes, i had to go a little lower on the wire.. I used SessionBindInfo, SmppClientSession and SubmitSm

Comment: Dear @Costa please provride full working code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the below sample code . I think you are missing the SystemType parameter.  The send operation works fine with me .

```
// Initialize Connection 
        client = new SmppClient();
        properties = client.Properties;
        properties.SystemID = "BBBB";
        properties.Password = "BBBB";
        properties.Port = 1234; //IP port to use
        properties.Host = "1.2.3.4"; //SMSC host name or IP Address
        properties.SystemType = "EXT_SME"; 
        properties.DefaultServiceType = "EXT_SME";
        //Resume a lost connection after 30 seconds
        client.AutoReconnectDelay = 3000;

        TextMessage send_msg = new TextMessage();

        send_msg.DestinationAddress = mobile_number; //Receipient number
        send_msg.SourceAddress = "1234"; //Originating number
        send_msg.Text = message;
        send_msg.RegisterDeliveryNotification = true; /
        client.SendMessage(send_msg);
        general_obj.WriteLog(mobile_number +" "+message, "SendLog");
```